# JQuery Mobile listview Search Filter

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am currently working with jQuery mobile and am using the search filter however it displays all the results as long as they contain the character. I want it to only display results which start with the character I search for? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [demo](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/listviews/listview-filter-autocomplete.html) on the jqm website where the listviewbeforefilter event is handled to fill the list. You could adapt the code to suit your needs.